# How do I change navigationBar font in Swift?

Tags: swift, uinavigationbar, navigationbar

This is what I have tried so far, but receiving an error (I have correctly implemented CaviarDreams to the project):

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = NSFontAttributeName[UIFont .fontWithName(CaviarDreams.ttf, size: 20)]
```

Error says: `Use of unresolved identifier 'CaviarDreams`

Answer (score 98, accepted):

Try this:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
```

**Edit:** Now, UIFont must be unwrapped to be able to be used here.

**Swift 5** (+ safe handling of optional `UIFont`)

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Caviar-Dreams", size: 20) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 20)]
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks. Have been fumbling around with this for an hour or so, trying to figure it out myself, Swift you know, kinda new to it. :P

Comment: Note: `NSFontAttributeName` is now of type `String` so this code doesn't work.

Comment: @Dehli don't understand how to fix this. Do you have suggestions?

Comment: NSFontAttributeName is still a String. I think Dehli meant that UIFont(...) now returns a UIFont? instead of a UIFont. See UIFont.h for details. benaneesh's answer solves the error relating to these that you'll see when you upgrade to the latest Xcode.

Comment: For Swift 4, ```NSFontAttributeName``` was renamed. It is ```titleTextAttributes =  [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 23)]``` now.

Answer (score 44):

Using Swift, I added this to `AppDelegate.swift` in

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.

        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "DINNextLTW04-Regular", size: 20)!
        ]

        return true
    }
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Your solution is awesome.

Comment: Modeled it after you my friend :)

Comment: Much better approach. Thanks!

Comment: `NSFontAttributeName` was now changed to --->> `NSAttributedStringKey.font`

Answer (score 12):

Swift 2.0:

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial-Regular", size: 30)!
        ]

        return true
    }
```

Or

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  self.navigationController?.navigationBarHidden =  false
  self.title = "SAMPLE"

//Set Color
  let attributes: AnyObject = [ NSForegroundColorAttributeName: UIColor.redColor()]
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = attributes as? [String : AnyObject]


//Set Font Size
  self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Arial", size: 37.0)!];

 }
```

Comment: Hi Alvin, when I put in your font size line in viewDidLoad() (xcode 7.3.1), it compiles fine but at (simulator) run time it crashes with EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION (code=EXC_1386_INVOP, subcode=0x0) with console msg "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value". I have the navigation bar in the FirstViewController of a tabbed view template. Might you have any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: This works now: UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
            NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.blueColor(),
            NSFontAttributeName : UIFont(name: "Bradley Hand", size: 28)!
        ]

Answer (score 10):

Now you have to unwrap (!) it first so its not of type `UIFont?`:

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "<font-name>", size: <size>)!]
```

Answer (score 4):

For Swift 2.3

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "Roboto-Bold", size: 20.0)!, NSForegroundColorAttributeName : UIColor.whiteColor()];
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
if let font = UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 16) {

 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

}
```

Or as the other answer recommended doing it on the AppDelegate:

```
  if let font = UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 16) {

    UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [
          NSAttributedStringKey.font: font]

}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

> Change **Large Title**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)]
```

> Change **Small Title** *when layout scrolled down*

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  // Override point for customization after application launch.

  let font = UIFont(name: "FontName", size: 16) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 16)
  UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [.font: font]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 4.2**

```
 self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedString.Key.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 18.0)!]
```

Comment: You can do just `.font` instead of `NSAttributedString.Key.font`