# Changing NavigationItem title size

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationitem

I put the title in a nevegationItem:

```
let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
navigationItem.title = "Title"
navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]
```

this works perfect... but.

How do I change the size of the text of Title..?

Comment: Create a label with your desired size and alignment. And set as titleView object. That's it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the font in the navigation bar…

```
let font = UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 22)!
UINavigationBar.appearance().titleTextAttributes = [NSFontAttributeName: font]
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 4.2**

> Change **Large Title**

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.largeTitleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 22)]
```

> Change **Small Title** *when layout scrolled down*

```
self.navigationController!.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [.font: UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 14)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Changing the title font by using the font attributes

```
self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [ NSFontAttributeName: UIFont(name: "CaviarDreams", size: 20)!]
```

found: [How do i change navigationBar font in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388214/how-do-i-change-navigationbar-font-in-swift)

Comment: Can i put a subtitle?

Comment: @JoséNeto If you want a subtitle in your navigation menu, you should create a new UIView and 2 UILabels and set this as navigationItem titleView