# Is it possible to change the font size of a UINavigationBar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar

In my application, I don't really have much space in the `NavigationBar`. Is it possible to change the font size of the text? I saw an answer, but this doesn't work in swift 4.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do i change navigationBar font in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388214/how-do-i-change-navigationbar-font-in-swift)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, Possible 
As you asked in **Swift 4**

```
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = [NSAttributedStringKey.font: UIFont(name: "Helvetica", size: 23)!]
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: Great Im going to test this asap.

Answer (score 0):

What's about using, this works only with iOS 11

```
navigationController.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
```